# Windows Phone 7: open a pdf file from the transfers directory

Tags: windows-phone-7, pdf

Like a said in the title, i need to open a pdf that i have downloaded in the shared/transfers directory. Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: have you heard about pdf launcher apps?

Comment: Yes, i´ve heard. But this is not the point. I´ve created a app that download a pdf file from a private server and store it in the "shared/transfers" directory. The point is: the pdf file is completely hidden, i cannot see the pdf that i´ve downloaded, neither the adobe reader app can recognize it.

Comment: Nobody knows the answer?